# Evaluate LastPage when compiling with pdflatex from python

Tags: pdftex, lastpage

Actually not sure if this belongs here or rather to stackoverflow...

I have a Python script that generates a report

```
p = Popen(['pdflatex', 'rendered.tex', '-job-name', 'out', '-output-directory', tmp_dir], cwd='static/latex')
p.communicate()
```

That works fine so far, the only problem I have is that as it compiles only once, the `LastPage` reference from the `lastpage` package is not evaluated so I get `??`. Is there a way to have the reference evaluated when compiling with `pdflatex` from console?

Comment: A possible simple solution would be to call `latexmk` instead of pdflatex in order to perform the required number of compilations.

Comment: @po.pe Can't you simply run the compilation twice?

Comment: @frougon yes that indeed works, I was just hoping there's another way but as I think about it there's probably not. So I'll go with just calling the pdflatex command twice and maybe change to `latexmk` somewhen in the future.

Comment: `latexmk` will also have to compile at least twice if you want correct output (it is only a wrapper). Typically, the first pass writes to a file, the second pass also but can use what the first pass wrote to the file, which takes into account the whole document.

Comment: That's understood